# if checkbox not selected need to stay on same page else redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need to validate the checkbox fields before submitting the form and create a validation message showing "Please select one item." as an alert.
But now the alert is showing, but the page redirects me to another page. Instead, I need to stay on the current page if no item is selected.

This is my script on Payment.htm:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert();
        $('#form').submit();
    var name="";
    var add = 0;
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var flag1=0;
    var flag2=0;
    var checkboxes = form.getElementsByClassName('sum'); 
    for (var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
          add += parseInt(checkboxes[i].value, 10);
          name+="#"+checkboxes[i].name;
          flag1=1;
      }
      else
      {

      name="No items selected";

      flag2=1;

      }
    }
    if(flag1==0 && flag2==1)
    {
    alert(name);  


    }
    else
    {

    alert("name and amount set");


    var p =  add;
    var price = p ; 
    var text=name ;

    localStorage.setItem("text", text);
    localStorage.setItem("price", price);
    $('#form').submit();
    }
});
});


//this is my form on payment.htm
<form method="post" action="makepayment.php" id="form">                                 

<table style="width:230px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #f0f0f0;font-size:14px;">
<tr style="background-color:#f0f0f0;">
  <th style="width:200px;text-align:left;">Select Items</th>
  <th align="center"></th>      
</tr>

<tr>

  <td>3 ヶ月コース契約 450,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id1" name="3 ヶ月コース契約 450,000 円" value="450000" ></td>      
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6 ヶ月コース契約 750,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id2" name="6 ヶ月コース契約 750,000 円" value="750000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>12 ヶ月コース契約 1,200,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id3" name="12 ヶ月コース契約 1,200,000 円" value="1200000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100 ポイント付与契約 10,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id4" name="100 ポイント付与契約 10,000 円" value="10000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>300 ポイント付与契約 30,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id5" name="300 ポイント付与契約 30,000 円" value="30000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>500 ポイント付与契約 50,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum"  id="id6" name="500 ポイント付与契約 50,000 円" value="50000" ></td>       
</tr>
</table>
<span id="error"></span>
<p style="text-align:center;">
<button  class="button" id="btnsubmit" > Make Payment </button>
<!--<input  class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">  -->      
<!--<a href="makepayment.php" class="button" onclick="check();">Make Payment</a></p>-->
</form>
```

Comment: If you found not check a radio, immediate `return` from here.I didn't see any return statement for invalid input. Also remove `$('#form').submit();` before checking, because it submits your form before validate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  
You might find helpful hints on formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your response,i tried it in my code

Comment: @JibyJohn see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to validate your form. So follow the code. you check first that if any checkbox is checked. If checked, then your form is valid and in this case you submit your form else you show a alert and prevent form submit.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnsubmit').on('click', function(e){
        var name="";
  var add = 0;
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var flag1=0;
  var flag2=0;
  var checkboxes = form.getElementsByClassName('sum'); 
    
    if ($('.sum:checked').length > 0) {
   alert("name and amount set");


   var p =  add;
   var price = p ; 
   var text=name ;

   localStorage.setItem("text", text);
   localStorage.setItem("price", price);
   $('#form').submit();
    }else{
   name="No items selected";
   alert("No item selected");
   return;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="makepayment.php" id="form">                                 

<table style="width:230px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #f0f0f0;font-size:14px;">
<tr style="background-color:#f0f0f0;">
  <th style="width:200px;text-align:left;">Select Items</th>
  <th align="center"></th>      
</tr>

<tr>

  <td>3 ヶ月コース契約 450,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id1" name="3 ヶ月コース契約 450,000 円" value="450000" ></td>      
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6 ヶ月コース契約 750,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id2" name="6 ヶ月コース契約 750,000 円" value="750000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>12 ヶ月コース契約 1,200,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id3" name="12 ヶ月コース契約 1,200,000 円" value="1200000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100 ポイント付与契約 10,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id4" name="100 ポイント付与契約 10,000 円" value="10000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>300 ポイント付与契約 30,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum" id="id5" name="300 ポイント付与契約 30,000 円" value="30000" ></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>500 ポイント付与契約 50,000 円</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="sum"  id="id6" name="500 ポイント付与契約 50,000 円" value="50000" ></td>       
</tr>
</table>
<span id="error"></span>
<p style="text-align:center;">
<input type="button"  class="button" id="btnsubmit" value="Make Payment" >
<!--<input  class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">  -->      
<!--<a href="makepayment.php" class="button" onclick="check();">Make Payment</a></p>-->
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for ypur help.The code worked for me and i got the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
i changed the code like this,but it does not redirect me to makepayment.php after selecting checkbox 


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert();

    var name="";
    var add = 0;
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var flag1=0;
    var flag2=0;
    var checkboxes = form.getElementsByClassName('sum'); 
    for (var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
          add += parseInt(checkboxes[i].value, 10);
          name+="#"+checkboxes[i].name;
          flag1=1;
      }
      else
      {

      name="No items selected";

      flag2=1;

      }
    }
    if(flag1==0 && flag2==1)
    {
    alert(name);  
        return false;

    }
    else
    {

       alert("name and amount set");


    var p =  add;
    var price = p ; 
    var text=name ;

    localStorage.setItem("text", text);
    localStorage.setItem("price", price);
    $('#form').submit();

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your code, but I'll provide you with "my way".

1) create button (but not with submit type)

2) make onclick event for button:

```
event.preventDefault(); validation_function()
```

3) validate form

4) if form OK then submit form like so:

```
document.getElementById('form_id').submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the JS pseudo-code:

```
if(checkbox:selected){
  document.location.href = /*new url*/
}
return false;
```